# Searching metadata

Tags: search-results

I am wanting a way to search metadata within the version history. To better explain, projects are given a unique number. This project number is assigned in a column to files associated to the project. Upon project completion, files are checked in. The next project is then assigned and may have overlap with the previous project's files. The new project number replaces the old project number upon check out of the files. Viewing the version history of a particular file shows the metadata of both project numbers.
I would like to run a search on a particular project number (i.e 1234) and return all versions of all files that contain that number (1234) within that column (Project Number column).

Thank you!

Comment: have u seen similar topc https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93213/can-sharepoint-2013-do-full-text-search-also-in-older-versions-of-a-document . I also suppose that this is not possible OOTB.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box. Properly configured, the crawl account only indexes the "tip" revision of any document. You might consider changing your process to create a new version of the document (possibly in a new folder) that is tagged with the new project number.

Comment: Thank you for the input! I don't think we can make a new version for every project. There are 10,000+ files and some have 100+ revisions. I will look into other methods. Again, thank you.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of documentations to copy for every project. What kind of project is it?