# Can SharePoint Online search version history?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, version-history, advanced-search

I'd like to be able to search for a term and then refine the results with a certain date and be able to see a past version of a document.

I've seen other questions asking about past versions of SharePoint but nothing about Online out of the box. ([Can SharePoint 2013 do full text search also in older versions of a document?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93213/can-sharepoint-2013-do-full-text-search-also-in-older-versions-of-a-document))

Answer (score 0):

No changes in functionality has been made in this respect with regards to SharePoint Online versus on-prem.

Answer (score 0):

So far, we can't do this, both online and on-prem versions can't do it.

As a workaround, you can export version history, which makes it easy for you to view.

You can refer to this similar situation below:
[Exporting item list version history](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190021/exporting-item-list-version-history)